# Answers which reference lucid24.org

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, references

Sometimes someone may flag the fact that [@frankk](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/16297/frankk?tab=profile) includes references to lucid24.org -- for example in [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/38884/254).

I believe it's generally permitted for an author to reference their own work published on another site, if:

- It's on-topic to the OP's question
- They disclose that it's their own work
- Their answer on this site isn't only a hyperlink

For further details, see [How to not be a spammer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) -- which says, among other things,:

> However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.

I believe that frankk has done this: the user profile says ...

> http://lucid24.org/ Contains my pali + english translations of suttas, and notes on EBT (early buddhist texts).
>
> http://notesonthedhamma.blogspot.com/ my analysis and commmentary on EBT sutta passages

... and this answer says ...

> I've done a thorough study of the 16 steps here:

... so it's certainly "disclosing affiliation".

Therefore I suppose that the references in @frankk's answers generally comply with these guidelines and don't automatically need flagging.

If you disagree, and think that the reference shouldn't be included in a given answer, then please explain why?

Answer (score 2):

An answer can't *Just* link to an external site, it must make an actual attempt to answer the question on SE, even if in short form.

Comment: IMO [this one](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/38884/254) did not specifically answer the question on-site (and the hyperlink too was to a related topic but not to a direct answer). So that answer should be downvoted or deleted, not because it references the author's own site, but because it's [a "hyperlink only" answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/139866) .

Comment: That is correct, agreed

Answer (score 0):

I guess the worst thing that could happen is if someone made an offsite collection of misinformation which wouldn't be ok for the SE but the link would be ok because nobody has time to quality check the offsite resources.

I tend to link my personal notes occasionally and in theory i could say things therein are excerpts when they are clearly not representative of the Sutta expression & meaning, kind of what Dhammadhatu does but offsite.